# How to submit a form with two buttons when a Token is used - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following two buttons, one to submit the form, and the other to save a draft.

```
<form action="{{route('post.create')}}" method="post">

 <button onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please wait...';this.form.submit();" class="btn btn-primary" align="right">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">


 <button onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please wait...';this.form.submit();" class="btn btn-outline-primary" align="right" style="font-size:8px;font-weight: bold">Save draft</button>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">

</form>
```

I have read that in order to have two submit buttons, I will differentiate between them via the name or value, so how do I do this when I'm using the above mentioned tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a name property to buttons inside a form. You also dont need 2 inputs with the same values so i removed 1.

```
<form action="{{route('post.create')}}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
  <button name="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please 
    wait...';this.form.submit();" class="btn btn-primary" align="right">Submit</button>

  <button name="draft" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending, please 
   wait...';this.form.submit();" class="btn btn-outline-primary" align="right" style="font-size:8px;font-weight: bold">Save draft</button>

</form>
```